# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin\jmtp.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, dll, unsatisfiedlinkerror, launch4j

I am creating a windows application, I need to create an installer for that for that I used Launch4J software.

It is throwing me an error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin\jmtp.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform while running it.

I did not find in google a 64 bit jmtp.jar and jmtp.dll file.

Please help me to sort out it.

[image]

Comment: check out first link in related column at right bottom of the screen , it may help you.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you have a 32-bit dll that you're trying to load while running a 64-bit JRE. Try setting a JAVA_HOME (and adding the path) to a 32-bit JRE.

Comment: @radai: I searched for 64 bit .dll file but I did not find any where. If you know the link, please share.

Answer (score 2):

64 bit JVM can emulate 32 bit mode. Use `-d32` command line parameter. It is supported since java 7.

Comment: I did not understand, please explain me bit more.

Comment: The launch configuration of your application in eclipse has a "JRE" tab. Enter `-d32` in "VM properties".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a 32-bit JVM for this application.